# How do I assert this method call by AssertWasCalled without testing the method parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I want to check whether **LogNotInRange** method is called and I want to ignore testing with what method parameters it was called; I am just interested if **LogNotInRange** was called or not.

**What is the correct Rhino Mocks syntax for it (I gave what I have been trying below:) ?**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void MyTestMethod()
        {
            var logger = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ILogManager>();
            var teleporter = new Teleporter() {LogEventManager = logger};
            var message = new message() {IsDone = false};

            teleporter.Teleport(message);

            // How should I specify parameter1 and parameter2?
            logger.AssertWasCalled(t => t.LogNotInRange(parameter1, parameter2));
        }



public void LogNotInRange (object parameter1, object parameter2)
{
    // some logging logic
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arg<T>.Is.Anything`:

```
logger.AssertWasCalled(t => t.LogNotInRange(Arg<object>.Is.Anything, 
                                            Arg<object>.Is.Anything));
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I had a problem to find out a clear explanation of AssertWasCalled.

Answer (score 1):

logger.AssertWasCalled(t => t.LogNotInRange(null, null), options => options.IgnoreArguments);